# Respond to output using stdin.write in python using paramiko

Tags: python

I am trying to write into stdin in python as `stdin.write("yes \n")` it works for me if the output displayed on the prompt is in 1 line,but the mentioned command fails if the output displayed on the prompt has  2 lines. I am using paramiko. Can you please help me on this?

```
Eg -   stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
       stdin.write('yes \n')
```

If the output on the cmd line is displayed after 2 lines asking for user response, the above command fails but works fine if the output is displayed in 1 line.

Comment: what happens when it fails?

Comment: Basically the stdin.write() is not getting executed as a result of which command is not getting executed